# Image Object: Вывод изображения в браузер

Tags: изображения, javascript

**Доброго времени суток!**

Я пытаюсь "прелоадить" изображения, а уже потом их отображать на веб странице. Использую для этого объект JavaScript - Image Object.

**Допустим, делаю так:**

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://bezrulya.ru/images/catalog/12000/12697.jpg";
img.width = 100;
img.height = 100;
img.name = "spant";
```

А как можно (если можно) вывести изображение, которое находится в объекте Image в браузер?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует несколько вариантов решения:

1-й: После полной загрузки картинка вставляется в нужное место

```
img.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('#first_img_place').appendChild(img);
}
```

2-й: В HTML сразу есть картинки в нужных местах с src='loading.gif', который показывает крутящийся индикатор загрузки. У каждой картинки есть атрибут id.

```
img.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('#first_img').src = img.src;
}
```

Что для первого, что для второго варианта необходимо соответствие между src и местом, куда надо эту картинку вставить. Например, в виде массива

Comment: Неплохо! Благодарю. Первый способ характеризует то, как, оказывается, работает объект Image в JavaScript. Век живи - век учись =) Ваш ответ принимается.

Answer (score 1):

Не поверишь:

```
<img src="http://bezrulya.ru/images/catalog/12000/12697.jpg" width="100" height"100" alt="машинко">
```

или скриптом

```
$("#someimg").attr("src","http://bezrulya.ru/images/catalog/12000/12697.jpg");
...
```

Comment: Возможно, я неверно поставил вопрос. Дело в том, что мне нужно вывести не изображение в браузер "любой ценой", а вывести изображение, находящееся в объекте Image.

Comment: прелоад для картинок этим методом делают для того, чтобы картинка попала в кэш. потом когда она понадобится, будет взята из кэша. поэтому при старте страницы загружают список картинок, потом их показывают. объект инициирует загрузку просто.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, собственно, это и пытаюсь сделать. Нужна лишь информация о том, как их оттуда( из объекта Image ) вытаскивать =)

Comment: это делает браузер. и делает он это по url картинки. если картинка загружена по указанному url, то она будет взята из кэша, и не будет грузиться повторно. ничего дополнительного кроме указания src для соответствующего img-элемента не нужно делать.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, т.е, скажем, особой пользы не будет от того, что я, скажем, загружу в кэш 10-20 картинок, а уже в процессе взаимодействия со страницей, они будут отображаться?

Comment: [3 метода прелоада картинок](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/). Т.е. картинки просто грузятся заранее, а использовать загруженные картинки именно из созданных объектов необходимости нет.

Comment: Польза от прелоада есть в случае медленных инет-соединений, а также большого количества картинок, которые должны появляться мгновенно при действиях посетителя. Для hover картинок, например, не очень красиво выглядит когда картинка прогружается, а не появляется сразу.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо большое за доки. Но основной способ(второй способ прелоада) есть способ, показанный пользователем @Photon. 

---
По поводу второго комментария: вы точно угадали мою задачу =)

---
Спасибо вам!